# How to add array to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, arrays, youtube

Here is the working code with the array at the bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/bwadtsg4/

```
(function initCover() {
  function coverClickHandler() {
    videoPlayer.play();
  }

  const cover = document.querySelector(".play");
  cover.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
}());

videoPlayer.init([
  "0dgNc5S8cLI",
  "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
  "CHahce95B1g",
  "2VwsvrPFr9w"
]);
```

Here is the working code **where I am trying to place the array** at the bottom: https://jsfiddle.net/89Leo0dq/

```
videoPlayer.init({
  afterPlayerReady: function initCover() {
    manageCover.init(function playVideo() {
      videoPlayer.play();
    });
  }
});
```

How do I place the array at the bottom in that code?

And here was as far as I got in my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/3s2p0bxm/

Where I was able to get up to this part, which is where I got stuck in trying to figure out what to do next in the code.

```
videoPlayer.init({
  afterPlayerReady: function initCover() {
    manageCover.init(function playVideo() {
      videoPlayer.play();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
videoPlayer.init({
  afterPlayerReady: function initCover() {
    manageCover.init(function playVideo() {
      videoPlayer.play();
    });
  }
}, [
  "0dgNc5S8cLI",
  "mnfmQe8Mv1g",
  "CHahce95B1g",
  "2VwsvrPFr9w"
]);
```